# Is it possible to define a class property dynamically in php?

Tags: php, class

I have a class definition like:

```
class JConfig {
    var $offline = '0';
    var $editor = 'tinymce';
    var $list_limit = '20';
    var $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org';
    var $log_path = '/path/to/logs';
    // ....
}
```

I want to dynamically define '$log_path'

I've tried to define a constant outside the class declaration but no luck with that

Example:

```
if(!defined('ROOT_PATH')){
    define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
}
class JConfig {
    var $offline = '0';
    var $editor = 'tinymce';
    var $list_limit = '20';
    var $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org';
    var $log_path = ROOT_PATH . '/logs'; // This generates a error
    // ....
}
```

But I cannot do that, is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not do it in the __construct method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in the class [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
class JConfig {
    var $offline = '0';
    var $editor = 'tinymce';
    var $list_limit = '20';
    var $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org';
    var $log_path;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->log_path = ROOT_PATH . '/logs';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use constants or variables in your class property default values. I suggest you just set them in the constructor...